# How to count the elements in array which are more than one (php)

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, count

In php,I have one ArrayList. Lets say

> > $list = {1000,7000,5000,1000,6000,5000,1000,2000};

So what I want to do is that Make count of each element in list:

> For example as above ,
>
> ```
>       1000 comes three times then count of 1000 = 3
>
>       5000 comes two times then count of 5000 = 2,etc.
> ```

And I want to `access that count of different elements separately`.

**Edit:**

Here I have for loop

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($trip);$i++)
    {
        // Here list will be new everytime for loop run.
        $list = $Users->Matches($trip[$i]);
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Here what I want to do is that "Take all the element of list for value of 
    $i : 0 to count($trip)" and "add it into another list lets say $allList 
    and access" as below :
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $cnt_arr = array_count_values($allList);

    foreach($cnt_arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "\n\n Count of ".$key." = ".$value." ";
    }
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
    Lets say for loop runs first time :
    $list = {1000,7000,5000}
    Now for loop second time :
    $list = {8000,1000,9000}

    Now for loop is completed and at the end I want the $allList value as below :
    $allList = {1000,7000,5000,8000,1000,9000}(which has all the elements of above-appended list)
```

So How can I do this ?

Please Guide me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `array_count_values` like

```
$cnt_arr = array_count_values($list);

foreach($cnt_arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Count of ".$key." = ".$value."<br>";
}
```

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

As per your edit,You need to store them like array like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($trip);$i++)
{
    // Here list will be new everytime for loop run.
    $temp_list = $Users->Matches($trip[$i]);
    foreach($temp_list as $tmp) {
        $list[] = $tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It works ok for array_count_values($list). But for echo "Count of ".$key." = ".$value."<br>"; It is printing like this Count of 0 = 1000<br>

Comment: Consider that we need foreach of `$cnt_arr`

Comment: Please see my edited question. I expect positive reply from you. And I will accept your answer.Thanks.

Comment: Ok I have seen.Can you show me the output array that you want?\

Comment: I have added output to question.Please see it.Thanks.

Comment: I dont want to merge for only two times.I want to merge $list every time for loop runs.I just gave an example that of two lists.Basically I want to append list.

Comment: In that case you see as per my new edit you need to use `list[]`