# PHP - Count Unique Word and Add Counted Prefix

Tags: php, count, unique, prefix, implode

I tried this

```
$data = "air;air;air;bus;air;air;bus;air;air";
$a = substr_count($data,"air");
$b = substr_count($data,"bus");
$data = implode($a . ' x ', array_unique(explode('air;', $data)));
echo $data;
```

And I get

```
7 x bus;7 x air
```

What I actually want to get is

```
7 x air 2 x bus
```

Help please..

Comment: You say you wanted to count words, so why are you actually counting single letters instead?

Comment: `echo implode($a . ' x ', array_unique(explode('air;', $data)));` - that makes so little sense, I would not even know where to start ... Just explode your string at the `;`, and then use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @CBroe - sorry i made typo mistake. I have revised it into counting word.

Comment: So what is with that overly complicated last line, why don't you simply do `echo $a . ' x air ' . $b . ' x bus';` ...?

Comment: @CBroe - Because I want to replace $data - (I just revised my code again to better reflex it. Sorry)

Comment: Well then replace the `echo` in that line I gave you, with `$data = ` ...?

Comment: @CBroe - when $data="air"; I get 1 x air 0 x bus - I actually want just air. And if $data = ''; I want to display nothing.

Comment: That's why using `array_count_values` would be a good idea to begin with - because values that don't _occurr_, won't get _counted_ either. And from the result of that function call, you can easily assemble the desired output.

Comment: Very near duplicate: [Count and display occurrences of unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1170807/2943403) and [How to count the elements in array which are more than one (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18547718/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode` function to make an array from the string and then use [`array_count_values`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which returns an array with the count of all the values.

```php
<?php
$data = "air;air;air;bus;air;air;air;air";

$arrayData = explode(';', $data);
$counts = array_count_values($arrayData);

$parsedData = '';
foreach ($counts as $key => $val) {
    $parsedData .= $val > 1 ? "$val x $key, " : "$key, ";
}

echo rtrim($parsedData, ', ');
```

**Note:** `array_count_values` is case-sensitive and if you want to count the values with case-insensitive, first you need to make the whole string upper case or lower case using `strtoupper` or`strtolower`.

Comment: I want to replace $data with 7 x air 2 x bus - (I just revised my code in question again to better reflex it. Sorry)

Comment: @Pekzz I changed my code. I like to create a new variable because "Explicit is better than implicit", but you can replace `parsedData` with `data` wherever it's used.

Comment: @Pekzz the values can be only `air` and `bus`? If there's no bus, still you want to show it in the result?

Comment: Thank you. This works well. However, sometimes my initial $data only contains air or bus or nothing. How to display only air or bus or nothing without showing 1 x ?

Comment: @Pekzz, You're welcome. I updated the code and added `array_filter` to filter out all empty values from the array. If we give an empty string to explode, it will return an array containing an element, which is an empty string.

Comment: The empty works. But I still get 1x air if $data="air". Is there easy way to display just air or bus, if the count is only 1? So it will not show 1 x air or 1 x bus. Instead it will show air or bus. The count only when it's more then 1. For example 2 x bus, etc

Comment: Updated the code and used ternary, Also, added a comma to output for better styling. you can remove it. The `rtrim` method will trim the given string from the right-hand side since we have an extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked! However you did something weird to display it.

If we use the simplest way to show it you can see it works:

```
<?php
$data = "air;air;air;bus;air;air;bus;air;air";

$a = substr_count($data,"air");
$b = substr_count($data,"bus");

echo $a . ' x ' . 'air' . ' ' . $b . ' x ' . 'bus';
```

However this can be more dynamic:

```
<?php
$data = "air;air;air;bus;air;air;bus;air;air";

$words = array_unique(explode(';', $data));

foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo substr_count($data, $word) . ' x ' .$word;
    echo ' ';
}
```